# HAProxy downloads PHP files instead of displaying in browser

Tags: nginx, haproxy, php-fpm, fastcgi

I have nginx and php-fpm running on Docker. When using the hostname of my Docker system (docker1.freekb.net), the phpinfo.php page displays in the browser, thus I know that I have nginx and php-fpm properly configured to serve PHP pages. Here is the server block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf. Requests from nginx on port 80 are forwarded onto PHP on port 9000.

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         stage.freekb.net;
    root                /var/www/stage;
    index               index.html phpinfo.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass 0.0.0.0:9000;
        fastcgi_index phpinfo.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have HAProxy setup to forward requests onto nginx. Here is my listen block in /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg. When I go to http://haproxy.freekb.net/index.html, the nginx welcome page is displayed, thus I know that HAProxy is able to forward requests onto nginx.

However, when I go to http://haproxy.freekb.net/phpinfo.php, the phpinfo.php is downloaded to my local PC. I suspect this means there is something awry with fastcgi. I'm not sure what has to change in order for PHP pages to be displayed in the browser when using HAProxy.

```
listen nginx
    bind *:80
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    server nginx1 docker1.freekb.net:80 check
```

Comment: fastcgi listen usually on 127.0.0.1 and not on 0.0.0.0

Comment: Same issue with 127.0.0.1

Comment: lsof - Pi :9000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case others find this article, I want to share what I *discovered*. I was not clearing my web browsers cache/history after making an nginx/php-fpm change. All I simply had to do was to **clear my web browsers history** and now I am able to display the phpinfo.php page in my